# Citrix Sharefile Tickboxes Unticked

Tags: javascript, html, css, automation, citrix

So at my workplace, we use Citrix Sharefile for clients to send files, however I have been tasked to remove Admin privileges from all users as it has been misused oftenly. We have thousands of folders, I cannot seem to figure out a way to automate being able to untick this tickbox or even where to start.
[This is the tickboxes, the admin ones are the ones I want to untick for all users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4ICr.png)

Comment: I think you are probably better off using the SDK rather than automating the clicks in the admin webpage. See https://discussions.citrix.com/forum/1787-sharefile-sdks/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.